# Change objects classNames in intervals not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

I have the following JavaScript code.  The idea is to change each item's css class in intervals of 5seconds.

```
function flahsActiveRules() {

        var list = document.getElementById('listName');
        var items = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {

            var li = items[i];
            changeColor(li, 'itemSortOrange');
        }
    }

    function changeColor(item, myCSS) {

        item.className = myCSS;
        sleep(5000);
    }

    function sleep(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem here is, on the UI side, it does not look as if there is any delay between the item changes.  All of them seem to happen immediately, but when I debug the code in Chrome, I can very well see the elements are chaging at intervals.

How do I fix this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you know about `setInterval`?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Sun3c/

Comment: check this update http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Sun3c/

Comment: Thanks for that Arun P Johny, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Arun P Johny, this was the solution to my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Sun3c/

Here is the JavaScript listed in jsfiddle:

```
function flahsActiveRules() {

        var list = document.getElementById('listName');
        var items = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {

            (function (i) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        changeColor(items[i - 1], '');
                    }

                    changeColor(items[i], 'itemSortOrange');

                    if (i == items.length - 1) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            changeColor(items[items.length - 1], '');
                            flahsActiveRules();
                        }, 1000)
                    }
                }, i * 1000)
            })(i);
        }
    }


    function changeColor(item, myCSS) {

        item.className = myCSS;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike languages like C, Code in javascript is non-blocking.

So you cannot generate a delay by writing a long piece of code.

To generate delays you can use setTimeout or setInterval functions.

What you can do is.

```
function flahsActiveRules() {

    var list = document.getElementById('listName');
    var items = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {

        var li = items[i];
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
           changeColor(li, 'itemSortOrange');
        }, 5000 * i); 
    }
}

function changeColor(item, myCSS) {

    item.className = myCSS;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be best using the JavaScript function `setInterval`.

I have put together a little demo here http://jsfiddle.net/mDW56/ This demo includes jQuery, so as long as you are not against using this :)

```
$(function(){

    // get the items using jQuery
    var items = $('li');

    // set your starting index
    var index = 0;

    // create a variable which holds the id of the interval so you can clear it later            
    var i = setInterval(function(){

        // log some info. remove this when not debugging
        console.log('interval start. index value: ', index);

        // if the index is less than the length of the array
        if ( index <= items.length - 1 ){

            // get the li using jquery and the index. then add a class
            $(items[index]).addClass('item');
            // increment the index
            index ++;
        }
        else{
            // index greater than the items so clear the interval
            window.clearInterval(i);
            console.log('interval stop');
        }

    }, 5000);

});
```